# multitasking gestures

Tags: ipad, multi-touch, multitasking

I develop for iOS, and use an ipad2 with firmware 4.3.2, and xcode 3.2.5
multitasking gestures work fine,

I got the ipad of a friend which has firmware 4.3.3, but my xcode doesn't recognize it,
 * so I want to make this friends ipad be able to use the multitasking gestures, is the problem of not recognition because of the x code?, does the 4.3.3 only work with latest xcode?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work with Xcode 3.2.6 and iPad if you make sure you connect the iPad to Xcode and check the box "use for development". You may have to enter an admin password and allow Xcode to scan the specific build (the exact wording of the dialog is hazy - but there is a step where Xcode gathers info about 4.3.3 on the device if your Xcode build shipped before 4.3.3 did.)

I don't use Xcode 4 or 3.2.5 so I can't be sure this works in general and you may need to ask on the developer forums or check the release notes to see what the minimum level of Xcode is needed to work with 4.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to use Xcode 4 (I did). But since you mentioned it worked with your iPad 2, try to first register the device in the developer portal.